# apache2 redirect from domain to subfolder

Tags: url, redirect, apache2, mediawiki

I've successfully setup MediaWiki on Ubuntu with Apache2. I can access the site via `http://example.com/w/` and it redirects to `http://example.com/w/index.php` just fine.

I now want to be able to redirect `http://example.com` to `../index.php` but I cannot get it working. Here is my .conf file located in `/etc/apache2/sites-available`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin admin@example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/w
        DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
        ServerName site.com
        ServerAlias

        Alias /w /var/www/html/w

        <Directory /var/www/html/w>
                Options +FollowSymlinks +Indexes -Multiviews
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted

        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

I have not modified the `apache2.conf` default file, and there is no `.htaccess` file.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the issue by adding the following lines in my apache2 conf file, between the directory tags:

```
            RewriteEngine on
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
            RewriteRule (.*) /w/ [R=301]
```